# How do I execute a filter in Gmail for the current email in my inbox?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I know how to create a filter and once it's created it will execute this filter on all incoming mail. However is there a way to execute this filter on what I already have received?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Go to the list of filters in Settings, edit the filter you want to run, don't change anything, and before you click **Update filter**, check the box that says "Also apply filter to [x] matching conversations":

[image: Edit filter]

Be aware that this will affect *all* conversations that match the filter, not just conversations with the `Inbox` label.

Comment: This method is not working anymore, cant see the also apply filter option

Comment: @YamenNassif:  I almost missed it too.  It is the last checkbox (Also apply filter to matching conversations) on the second page.  Stylistically it looks just like all the other checkbox options so it is sort of hidden.

Comment: This ran not just on my inbox, but across all labels in my system. Now, I have a big mess.

Comment: Finally!  Thank you.  Why did they make that so difficult??